# How do I make a nation my protectorate?

Tags: empire-total-war

I'm running Minor Factions Revenge.

I can't seem to get myself a protectorate nation. It seems that I can only get it if I have a military alliance with that nation. According to [the fan wiki](http://empiretotalwar.wikia.com/wiki/Protectorate), I could get offer protectorate status in a peace treaty but apparently that's not possible.

How then do I make a nation my protectorate state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're at war with a nation fight until they are down to one province, then under diplomacy when you propose peace there should be a Become Protectorate button.

It's not guaranteed that they will accept though.